# Error While Running Kafka Server on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, window

while running kafka on windows.

```
C:\Program Files\kafka_2.12-2.1.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

And getting the error

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>   The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>   Error: Could not find or load main class Files\kafka_2.12-2.1.0.logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have spaces in the file path, e.g `Program Files`

There's no specific reason Kafka needs to be in your Program Files folder. You could move it to C:\kafka for example, and I've been able to run it on Windows 10 (out of my users folder), so it does work